# Componentes Swing: Ajustar Automáticamente Dimensiones Al Texto

Tags: java, eclipse

Java jdk 1.7 | Eclipse

Hola a todos

Al insertar un JLabel o un JButton y asignarles un Rótulo (Text | setText), este puede ser de una extensión mayor a la longitud predeterminada de los Componentes mencionados. El ajuste se hace desde los Controladores de Ajuste (los recuadros en los bordes y esquina), sin embargo es una tarea tediosa y en el mayor de los casos el Ajuste Manual genera longitudes mayores al Texto, lo que por ejemplo, al centrar los Componentes, se hace muy notorio en detrimento de un diseño de calidad.

**¿Existe alguna configuración o código que permita Autoajustar en forma exacta la longitud de los Componentes?**

Desde ya Muchísimas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes optar por estos metodos:

```
    setMinimumSize(width, height);
    setPreferedSize(width, height);
    setMaximumSize(width, height);
```

Si estos no funcionan, usa estos:

```
 setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
  setPreferedSize(new Dimension(width, height));
  setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```